# Leave Georgia (Sakartvelo) without motorcycle

Tags: customs-and-immigration, automobiles, georgia-country, import-taxes, motorcycles

I am an Estonian (EU) citizen entering Georgia (the country) by land with my own vehicle. I am granted entry for 1 year, but would like to leave my vehicle in Georgia and fly home within this time frame.

Is this possible? Do I need to perform temporary import / permission from the police for my vehicle to remain in Georgia without me?

I have been unable to find any information on the [www.gov.ge](https://gov.ge) website.

Comment: Not an expert on Georgia. Did you have to declare it at customs when entering Georgia? If yes, and you're leaving the country without it, you could face problems. If the customs officials were not interested in the motorcycle when you were entering the country, you could probably leave without it easily.

Comment: I haven't entered Georgia yet. In Turkey you have to get a permission from the police to leave the vehicle temporarily in the country while gone.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)#By_car It says foreign-registered vehicles can only stay in Georgia for up to 3 months... Even if you have a residence permit for one year, you should make sure your motorcycle is also allowed to stay. Other than that, I can provide no specific help...

Comment: I haven't read it, no - but good to know. It's actually unlikely I will be staying for more than 3 months anyway. The crucial question is wether I can temoprarily leave the country by air without my vehicle.

Comment: I would probably check customs regulations for Georgia, to find out whether you have to specifically declare your vehicle when entering Georgia. If not, you probably won't have to get a permit to leave the country without it...

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so I can answer my own question.

It seems that it's difficult to get any information about customs even when you're in the country.

The lowdown is this: like @Johnnyjanko said, your vehicle has 90 days (or 60 days apparently to some locals) after crossing the border by land, which will likely be different to your personal visa. Any duration outside of this timeframe will be fined at 50 GEL (~$20) per day up to a maximum of 1000 GEL on your vehicle.

When leaving by air (which I have done) nobody asks you any questions at the passport control, although I had a letter from the person where the bike is kept to confirm there is someone responsible during my absence.

That's it, it seems you don't need any permission. But if you go beyond the allowed duration, be prepared to pay a fine when leaving the country.